# Removing time stamp to include just the month and day

Tags: r

I have a table called "rejected_at" in the dataframe "Job_applications". The format is: "M/DD/YYYY H:M:S PM/AM". Now i want to create a new table that just has "M/DD". How would i do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGOSr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `rejected_at` column is just text, you could try using `sub` here:

```
x <- "12/30/2018 4:05:44 PM"
sub("/[^/]+$", "", x)

[1] "12/30"
```

Or, in your case:

```
Job_applications$new_col <- sub("/[^/]+$", "", Job_applications$rejected_at)
```

**Edit:**

If you also wanted to retain the year, then we can try using `sub` with a capture group targeting the full date:

```
sub("(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+).*", "\\1", x)

[1] "12/30/2018"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to `DateTime` class and then extract the `month` and `day`

```
v1 <- as.POSIXct(df1$rejected_at, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
format(v1, "%d")
format(v1, "%m")
```

Or if we the format needed is `%m/%d`

```
format(v1, "%m/%d")
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rejected_at = mdy_hms(rejected_at),
           day = day(rejected_at),
           month = month(rejected_at))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)

new_date <- mdy_hms("08/14/2017 09:59:06 PM")

new1 <- paste0(month(new_date),"/",day(new_date))
```

Comment: How is this different from @akrun answer?

Comment: i have only used lubridate and i when i was posting it i dont know what akrun has posted at that time.